# Model association in sails js

Tags: javascript, associations, sails.js, models, waterline

I want to create a model association of a model to two other models in SAILS.JS. But I get an error while compiling.

This model is User.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
    },
    google: {
        model:'Google'
    },
      facebook: {
        model:'Facebook'
    }
  }
};
```

This model is Google.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
      kind: 'string',
      gender: 'string',
      sub: 'string',
      name: 'string',
      given_name: 'string',
      family_name: 'string',
      profile: 'string',
      picture: 'string',
      email: 'string',
      email_verified: 'string',
      locale: 'string',
      user:{
        model:'User'
      }
  }
};
```

This model is Facebook.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
      name: 'string', 
      id: 'string', 
      user:{
          model:'User'
      }
  }
};
```

And I get the following error

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/waterline-schema/lib/waterline-schema/foreignKeys.js:104
    throw new Error(error);
          ^
Error: Trying to create an association on a model that doesn't have a Primary Key.
    at ForeignKeys.findPrimaryKey (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/waterline-schema/lib/waterline-schema/foreignKeys.js:104:11)
    at ForeignKeys.replaceKeys (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/waterline-schema/lib/waterline-schema/foreignKeys.js:53:27)
    at new ForeignKeys (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/waterline-schema/lib/waterline-schema/foreignKeys.js:30:10)
    at new module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/waterline-schema/lib/waterline-schema.js:30:17)
    at Waterline.initialize (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline.js:107:17)
    at buildORM (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/orm/build-orm.js:52:15)
    at Array.async.auto.instantiatedCollections (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/orm/index.js:203:11)
    at listener (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:490:46)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:441:17
    at _each (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:13)
    at Immediate.taskComplete (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:440:13)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17)
```

Comment: Well, 2 mins after posting the question i saw the problem. I used an id attribute in facebook model which is a primary key attribute. Hence the err. Solved.

Comment: you can post your own answer to the question. It'll make the answer more obvious for others.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Well, 2 mins after posting the question i saw the problem. I used an id attribute in facebook model which is a primary key attribute.
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes

Hence the err. Solved.

Comment: It always happens like that. :) Just FYI, if you would like to discuss any Sails.js issues in realtime with other users, check out our Gitter page. https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails